# There are several different ways of definition the ID. What is the difference?

Tags: android, android-resources

There are several different ways of definition the ID:

```
android:id="@id/android:list"
android:id="@+id/android:list"
android:id="@+id/confirm"
```

What is the difference?

Answer (score 4):

android:id="@id/android:list" refers to android.R.id.list. android.R contains resources that are bundled with the platform. There are lots of these standard resources, they are all [listed in the JavaDoc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.html).

@+ creates a resource, so android:id="@+id/confirm" creates a new id in your application's R class, ie. R.id.confirm. This is explained in the [User Interface > Declaring Layout > ID](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html#id) of the Dev Guide.

I'm not sure you can do android:id="@+id/android:list", as it would mean you are trying to create a resource on the platform's resource class.

Answer (score 1):

+id/label means that your resource will have an id value = label and that label belongs to your application's name space. 
There are many resources bundled with android.jar file and when referring to these resources you would say android:id = "@android:id/list" which means your resource will have an id value = list and that this value belongs to android name space.

Refer the following for details:
http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/dc8023b221351aa7

Answer (score 0):

The '+' means add it to your current project's R.java. Those without pluses are resources inherited from the framework.

Comment: this is what i got from the Dev Guide:

android:id="@+id/text1"
In this case we create a new id called text1. The + after the @ in the id string indicates that the id should be automatically created as a resource if it does not already exist, so we are defining text1 on the fly and then using it.

so, what is the "on the fly" mean?

Comment: Think of the externalized XML files as a mini dependency injection framework that defines the object graph of the widgets. As far as I know, the ids with + are for compile time usage (like generics). They tell the development tools in Eclipse what gets written into R.java